# Which openstack instance has a certain IP address

Tags: networking, openstack

There are IPs on my network that are not configured as fixed or floating in Neutron, they are simply claimed by an instance (e.g. via `ifconfig eth0:1 ip.add.re.ss`). How do I get openstack (possibly via neutron-openvswitch-agent?) to tell me which instance, if any, has claimed a certain IP? Or produce a list of such IPs?